# Applications of Hodge-Riemann bilinear relations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds, hodge-theory, hodge-structure

> I am wondering if the Hodge-Riemann bilinear relations have any further applications/ developments in Kahler or algebraic geometry.

Let me briefly remind the statement.

Given a compact Kahler manifold $(M,\omega)$ of complex dimension $n$, its cohomology with complex coefficients satisfies the Hodge decomposition $H^k(M,\mathbb{C})=\oplus_{p+q=k}H^{p,q}(M)$. [The hard Lefschetz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_hyperplane_theorem#Hard_Lefschetz_theorem) allows to define the primitive part $P^{p,q}\subset H^{p,q}(M)$. On $H^{p,q}$ one defines an hermitial form
$$Q(\xi)=i^{p-q}(-1)^{(n-k)(n-k-1)/2}\int_M\xi\wedge \bar\xi\wedge \omega^{n-k}.$$
**The Hodge-Riemann bilinear relations tell that this form $Q$ is positive definite on $P^{p,q}$.**

Answer (score 3):

Since you ask for *further* applications, does that mean you already know some? The Hodge-Riemann bilinear relations are used in all kinds of ways. Suppose that $M$ is a compact Riemann surface, then form the period matrix $P=(\int_{\gamma_i} \omega_j)$, where the $\gamma_i\in H_1(M,\mathbb{Z})$ and $\omega_j\in H^0(M,\Omega_M^1)$ are bases. The relations tell you that you can choose bases so that $P= (I,\Omega)$, with $\Omega^T=\Omega$, and $Im\Omega>0$. This is just the starting point for a long and beautiful story. Take a look at chapter 2 of Griffiths and Harris for more about this.

Comment: No, I do not know any applications, even in Chapter 2 of Griffiths-Harris most of which is about Riemann surfaces. Thus it would be helpful to have a reference to a concrete place in Chapter 2. Thank you so much.

Comment: I recommend Mumford's Tata Lectures on Theta I, e.g.pages 118, 134-5.  and more.  The point is that these relations allow one to define a map, the Torelli map,  from the set of isomorphism classes of curves, to a quotient of "Siegel space".